# How to compare 2 mysql dumps

Tags: mysql, bash

I've been testing the command

```
mysqldump databaseName > mysqlDump1
```

Run separately on 2 servers where I process same data against same software.

When I diff the outputted files, there are numerous differences (including the file size). I guess its datestamps etc that causes it, but is there a way that both dumps would be the same?

That way I can then use it to regression test software changes where I don't expect changes in DB when processing (unless my change is supposed to affect it...rare)

Comment: Do you not have unit tests/db integration tests?

Comment: Instead of comparing whole db you should compare only changed tables

Comment: What if you dump before a change/test and again after, are the diffs more managable than 2 different DBs? If your tests are not supposed to change the DB, then perhaps you only need to do 1 dump before all your tests, but if 1 test fails, it should put its dump as the new gold/silver file for the next test.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that `mysqldump` doesn't guarantee to dump rows in a consistent order. Even two dumps on the same data taken on the same machine could theoretically come out with inserts in a different order.

`mysqldump` does have an option `--order-by-primary`, which might help, but the documentation warns that it takes longer than an ordinary dump.